# getting NoMethodError: undefined method 'query' for main:Object error

Tags: calabash

While I enter the comment

Running irb... 1.9.3p374 :001 > query("label")

It throws the following error.
NoMethodError: undefined method 'query' for main:Object 
             from (irb):1 
             from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/irb:16:in '

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Hi could you explain more about what you have done. First you should have defined your step in step.rb file like `While /^I enter the comment "([^\"]*)"(\d+)$/ do .....  end` if you didn't define it you will get the above error "NoMethodError"

Comment: if you using UI queries and if you get the environment correctly setup query("label") should work else check query("view") is working if it doesn't work too tell us the steps you have done..

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the calabash library was not loaded when you started irb. Assuming you are using Calabash for iOS:

```
require 'calabash-cucumber/operations'
include Calabash::Cucumber::Operations
```

Answer (score 1):

Calabash ios has built in irb

```
calabash-ios console
```

After running above command you should see

```
$ calabash-ios console
Running irb...
irb(main):001:0>
```

If you are using ruby irb, then you will need to include the require gems. I would reccomand using the calabash-ios console.

If you would like to query on real device, you will need to set few things (Make sure you are using calabash-ios 0.9.144)

```
DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.0.100:37265 NO_LAUNCH=1 DEVICE=iphone OS=ios6 APP_BUNDLE_PATH=Debug-iphoneos/test.app DEVICE_TARGET=device calabash-ios
```

DEVICE_ENDPOINT - The device ip address which you are trying to connect to

OS -ios (ios4, ios5, ios6)

DEVICE_TARGET - simulator or device

DEVICE - iphone or ipad

APP_BUNDLE_PATH - if you are running it for real real device, you will need to set path of .app file. However, for simulator you should set the .xcodeproj

Hope this helps, it might be more info than you asked for.

For more info: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/calabash-ios/6T9wvcPOSN8